# Unable to compute ceiling for max when histogram overflowed

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, cassandra-3.0

When I am trying to run select query without where clause on a cassandra table, it is throwing an error

```
Connected to Test Cluster at 127.0.0.1:9042.
[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 3.11.3 | CQL spec 3.4.4 | Native protocol v4]

    cqlsh:ev_keyspace> select * from my_keyspace.my_table ;
    ServerError: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to compute ceiling for max when histogram overflowed
```

Also I checked the cassandra system.log file and foung the same error flooding

```
ERROR [CompactionExecutor:5397] 2019-08-06 09:59:03,523 CassandraDaemon.java:228 - Exception in thread Thread[CompactionExecutor:5397,1,main]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to compute ceiling for max when histogram overflowed
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.EstimatedHistogram.rawMean(EstimatedHistogram.java:231) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.3.jar:3.11.3]
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.EstimatedHistogram.mean(EstimatedHistogram.java:220) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.3.jar:3.11.3]
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.metadata.StatsMetadata.getEstimatedDroppableTombstoneRatio(StatsMetadata.java:115) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.3.jar:3.11.3]
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.format.SSTableReader.getEstimatedDroppableTombstoneRatio(SSTableReader.java:1926) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.3.jar:3.11.3]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.AbstractCompactionStrategy.worthDroppingTombstones(AbstractCompactionStrategy.java:423) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.3.jar:3.11.3]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy.getNextBackgroundSSTables(SizeTieredCompactionStrategy.java:99) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.3.jar:3.11.3]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy.getNextBackgroundTask(SizeTieredCompactionStrategy.java:183) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.3.jar:3.11.3]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.CompactionStrategyManager.getNextBackgroundTask(CompactionStrategyManager.java:153) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.3.jar:3.11.3]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.CompactionManager$BackgroundCompactionCandidate.run(CompactionManager.java:268) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.3.jar:3.11.3]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_181]
    at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.NamedThreadFactory.lambda$threadLocalDeallocator$0(NamedThreadFactory.java:81) [apache-cassandra-3.11.3.jar:3.11.3]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_181]



# nodetool cfhistograms my_keyspace my_table

    Percentile  SSTables     Write Latency      Read Latency    Partition Size        Cell Count
                                  (micros)          (micros)           (bytes)                  
    50%             0.00             42.51              0.00         107964792               NaN
    75%             0.00             51.01              0.00         962624926               NaN
    95%             0.00             61.21              0.00       14831182994               NaN
    98%             0.00             73.46              0.00       36904729268               NaN
    99%             0.00             88.15              0.00      132236317342               NaN
    Min             0.00             11.87              0.00              4769                 0
    Max             0.00           1358.10              0.00      1322363173429223372036854776000
```

I am not sure what is the meaning of this error and why it is throwing it. Can someone please help me understand this?

Comment: It looks like https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-11117, but it should be resolved in 3.11.3

Comment: thats possibly data corruption, are you using sstable compression?